# Exposing a Specific Action of a Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-resources

Using this as an example contexted:
Post has_many comments
Comment belongs_to post

I have a route that looks like:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

How do i create a route that exposes comments#index?

An example use case would be... I want to list ALL comments in the system on a page.  Essentially using the comments resource as if it's not nested when a user hits   /comments

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, :except => :index
end
match 'comments' => 'comments#index', :as => :comments
```

That said, I usually look to avoid routes like this because I like a tidy RESTful routes file, but sometimes it can't be helped.

Second option:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, :except => :index
  get :comments, :on => :collection
end
```

In the second option, you'd want to remove the `index` action from the comments controller and create a `comments` action in your posts controller.

Comment: Ah yes, i came up with this exact solution BUT i wasn't sure if it was right.  I feel like the recommendation is normally go 100% restful but pulling out that ONE url is not.

Comment: I posted an alternative that's more RESTful, but I'm not sure if it's at all superior.